# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object-reference

Getting this error on this code:

```
string pname = null;
pname = ag.FirstOrDefault().arrangement.parent.name;
```

when calling the line pname = ag.FirstOrDefault.....

The filed parent.name is empty(null), which is fine I want to get an empty(null) string in such case.
How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 6):

Either `ag` is null, the `FirstOrDefault` call is returning null, `arrangement` is null, or `parent` is null.

Only you are in a position to determine which one of those is actually the culprit.

Comment: +1 I would recomend use debuger or divide it into multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var obj = ag.FirstOrDefault();
if( obj !=null)
pname = obj.arrangement.parent.name ?? String.Empty;
```

or you can try

```
//This will set the variable to null:
  var obj = ag.FirstOrDefault();
    if( obj !=null)
    pname = Convert.ToString(obj.arrangement.parent.name);
```

Note : ag.FirstOrDefault().arrangement.parent.name is nullable type

Comment: This will throw an exception if `ag.FirstOrDefault()` return null

Comment: The filed parent.name is empty(null) -- this line is written by op anyways i am updating my ans

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the properties of a null object.  If ag.FirstOrDefault() will return null, then you will not be able to access `arrangement`.

```
var temp = ag.FirstOrDefault();
string pname = (temp!= null) ? temp.arrangement.parent.name : null;
```

You may need to do further null checking.

Answer (score 0):

If the property ag.FirstOrDefault().arrangement.parent.name is null it means the object **ag** is null also.  This is the reason you are getting object reference error.

The answer Leons provided is actually what I was going to suggest.  You need to do some research on the problem its one of the simplest thing to avoid ( trying to reference a null object ) in programming.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean `ag` is null. `ag` might be null; the output of `FirstOrDefault` might be null; the `arrangement` member might be null; the `parent` member might be null.